# Qt based apps have unreadable, tiny font sizes

Tags: debian, kde, qt

I'm running debian squeeze with Xfce 4.6. Today I logged onto my machine
and all Qt-based apps have really tiny font sizes. I took a screenshot with Kile, skype 2.6, Kate and gedit for comparison:
[image: screenshot]

The version of my KDE platform is something about 4.3. Any ideas how to reset to normal sizes?
Thank you very much!

Edit: KDE system settings:

[image: KDE system settings]

Some ways to set it via terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open KDE *System Settings* and then go to the *Application Appearance* / *Fonts* tab. Make sure that *Force fonts DPI* is unchecked or set it to a reasonable value.

You can also edit `~/.kde/share/config/kcmfonts` and set `forceFontDPI=0`. This is better done while not logged in KDE as the target user.

Comment: Thank you! But is there some way to set it via terminal? As KDE system settings also runs in Qt.. =(