# Qt applications have tiny fonts on XFCE

Tags: opensuse, xfce, qt

My question is almost the same as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68307/72907) but the answer did not work for me.

I'm running OpenSuse 13.1 with XFCE desktop.

I have set `~/.kde4/share/config/kcmfonts` with `forceFontDPI=0` but it didn't work.

I found on a forum that I could use `qtconfig`. When I run it, I can change the font size and the sample text now looks readable, but when I quit `qtconfig` asking to save changes, I get the following error:

```
X Error: BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter) 5
  Major opcode: 18 (X_ChangeProperty)
  Resource id:  0x0
```

Comment: Try using `systemsettings` .

Comment: @schaiba is this a console command or in Yast? Because I dont have such command

Comment: `zypper se systemsettings`

Comment: No packages found. I just installed XFCE by the way, not KDE. But cant find it in the kde packages

Comment: seems it's in the kdebase4-workspace.

Comment: Yup, just found it myself. Install that then change your settings as you desire.

Comment: So I have systemsettings installed, where should I get now? Being a Qt-based app, it's almost impossible for me to read the words

Answer (score 2):

- Try setting it directly in (`10` is the font size in the example):

  `~/.config/Trolltech.conf`

  ```
  [Qt]
  font="Sans Serif,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0"
  ```
- Or  for global settings:

  `/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf`

Comment: Didnt work, unless I need a complete reboot ? I changed the font size to 42, restarted a Qt app, but got the same tiny fonts. Same after logging out and back in my xfce session

Comment: +1 every time after relogging the font size in `~/.config/Trolltech.conf` resets  to original size

Comment: What are the other numbers for?

Answer (score 2):

Just found a solution:

1. OpenSUSE Menu → Settings → Settings Manager (graphical settings manager for xfce4).
2. In Appearance → Fonts: Check **Custom DPI** setting and set an appropriate value (`96` in my case).

Now, Qt-Based app's have readable fonts!

I remember doing exactly the same thing in the KDE desktop (checking custom DPI) but that did not work when I was login back in my Xfce session.